# HTML Canvas - Updating the canvas periodically

Tags: html, canvas

I have a canvas which I use to draw a plot periodically. I have a function that receives data periodically, and it parses the data and plots it on the canvas. For the plotting I use [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/).

But I am not able to update the plot periodically. I have confirmed that the data are received correctly and parsed, but the plot is not updating. It updates when I click the page, or if I minimize the browser and maximize it again. The plot would briefly appear and the next time update is called, the plot dissapears.

Here is my code. I am using Firefox.

```
    function start () 
    {
        // create a new websocket and connect
        window.ws = new wsImpl('ws://localhost:8181/consoleappsample', 'my-protocol');

        // when data is comming from the server, this metod is called
        ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
        {
            ParseIncomingData(evt.data);
        };

        // when the connection is established, this method is called
        ws.onopen = function () 
        {
            inc.innerHTML = 'Connected<br/>';
            textPanel.style.background = "#00FF00";

        };

        // when the connection is closed, this method is called
        ws.onclose = function () 
        {
            inc.innerHTML = 'Connection closed<br/>';
            textPanel.style.background = "#FF0000";
        }


        var periodicFuncID = setInterval( function() { ws.send(1); }, 2000);
    }

function ParseIncomingData(data)
{
    var splitContents = data.split(',');
    var inc = document.getElementById('incomming');

        var xaxis = new Array();
        var yaxis = new Array();

    yaxis   = splitContents;
    var dataType = yaxis.shift();

    var data;
    for(var i=1; i<=yaxis.length; i++)
    {
        xaxis.push(i);
    }

        data = 
    {
             labels : xaxis,
             datasets : [
                 {
                    //fillColor : "rgba(135,206,250,0.5)",
            fillColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(255,165,0,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#585858 ",
                    data : yaxis
                  }
                 ]
         }

         var canvas= document.getElementById('Plot'); 

         var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         var myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
}

window.onload = start;
```

Most of the code is unrelated to my problem but I just wanted to know if there is something wrong in the way I handle.

Thank you.

Comment: I was wondering about the rate of your data refresh, since you suggest (with click and resize experiment), that a slowdown 'helps'. So maybe Chart is always refreshing. To quick test this you simply define a global oneOnTen integer counter,  then at the start of ParseIncomingData : if (oneOnTenCounter++ % 10 != 0 ) return; (for instance).

Comment: Thank you GameAlchemist. I tried your method but it was giving the same results. I tried drawing rectangles in the canvas randomly, and found that when I have the last line "var myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);" it doesnt work. When I remove that it works fine. Maybe the Chart.js is using the canvas context in some way that is causing it?

Comment: https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/161#issuecomment-20487775  suggests that you should create once the Chart at your app start, then only call ChartObject.Line(data); (no new Chart each time)